# "I would stop missing you the moment we meet again"

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate the sentence in the title. Clearly,

> 君に会うと、会いたくなくなる。

seems to be wrong. Wouldn't this mean "When I see you, I would never want to see you again" or something like that?

How to say this simple sentence? My brain is shortcircuiting for some reason...

Comment: Just to understand what you are trying to convey, why is it not "I will stop..."?

Comment: @dainichi I offer [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=3KN4clxh5r4C&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=%22the+use+of+would%22#v=onepage&q=%22the%20use%20of%20would%22&f=false) and [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=VP_HO_Q5rEUC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%22the+use+of+would%22#v=onepage&q=%22the%20use%20of%20would%22&f=false) to explain that particular use of would. It's used to express tentativeness. I guess it works as a kind of a hedge.

Comment: Does your sentence more literally mean "I won't stop missing you until I see you again"?

Comment: No, it was in English, in response to 'When would you stop missing me'? I said 'only when I finally get to see you again'. I have this habit of translating convos into Japanese in my head, but kind of locked up there.

Comment: @Flaw, so this is Malaysian/Singaporean English? The reason I ask is that AFAIK, in standard English, "would" is used for counterfactual conditionals (and it would have to be "met"), and that changes the nuance of the question quite a bit.

Comment: No, I was paraphrasing. I don't think in standard English "would" is only used for counterfactual conditionals; in this case it is not definitely factual, so "When will you stop missing me" seems weird.

Comment: @user54609 Indeed. "I would stop missing you the moment we meet again" is only grammatical as a relative clause in a conditional. "I would stop missing you the moment we meet again, if I actually liked you and missed you in the first place; but I don't."

Comment: To say `only when I finally get to see you again` as a response to `When would you stop missing me`, I'd say 「会えば寂しくなくなる」.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"君に会うと、会いたくなくなる。" means "If I meet you, I will start wishing not to meet you."

In parts 君に会うと. The と is one of your four many options for if type expressions. But this particular one has a 前後 (before/after) connection some of the others lack. This means the event following in this case happens temporally after. So it could also be translated "After I meet with you, I start to wish I didn't meet you" or something roughly like that (the tense in the ～と clause is immaterial in Japanese).

The second half involves the following sequence:

> 会う to meet
>
> 会いたい to want to meet
>
> あいたくない to not want to meet
>
> あいたくなく  adverbialization of the constructon

なる in this case to become

ergo, I begin to not want to meet you.

Thus, together, whenever I meet with you, I start wishing I didn't meet you.

Comment: Exactly this. と is being used to mark a condition that brings about an event or state. It's important to note that when と is used in this way, the triggered event/state *must be **nonvolitional** / **uncontrollable***.

Comment: What would be the correct expression though? I was trying to translate the English to Japanese, and clearly made an epic fail.

Comment: From researching http://alc.co.jp, 恋しい and 寂しい were consistently used to convey the feeling of 'missing' someone. [恋しい](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E6%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%84&ref=sa) in particular. As for the proper [conditional](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/conditionals), -eba, -nara, or -tara would be applicable.

Comment: In terms of how I would say what you want to say...

[person's name]と会うまでに、この寂しさは終わらない。
but that would be until I meet you again, this loneliness will not end.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it like this:

```
君に会えたら、 If I were to meet you
必ず、 for sure
同時に、　in that same moment
この「君に会いたい」気持ちが消えちゃう。　this I-miss-you feeling would disappear.
```